# memory allocation vs. swapping (under Windows)

Tags: windows, swap, bad-alloc

sorry for my rather general question, but I could not find a definite answer to it:

Given that I have free swap memory left and I allocate memory in reasonable chunks (~1MB) -> can memory allocation still fail for any reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smartass answer would be "yes, memory allocation can fail for any reason". That may not be what you are looking for.

Generally, whether your system has free memory left is not related to whether allocations succeed. Rather, the question is whether your process address space has free [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

The allocator (`malloc`, `operator new`, ...) first looks if there is free address space in the current process that is already *mapped*, that is, the kernel is aware that the addresses should be usable. If there is, that address space is reserved in the allocator and returned.

Otherwise, the kernel is asked to map new address space to the process. This *may* fail, but generally doesn't, as mapping does not imply using physical memory yet -- it is just a promise that, should someone try to access this address, the kernel will try to find physical memory and set up the MMU tables so the virtual->physical translation finds it.

When the system is out of memory, there is no physical memory left, the process is suspended and the kernel attempts to free physical memory by moving other processes' memory to disk. The application does not notice this, except that executing a single assembler instruction apparently took a long time.

Memory allocations in the process fail if there is no mapped free region large enough and the kernel refuses to establish a mapping. For example, not all virtual addresses are useable, as most operating systems map the kernel at some address (typically, 0x80000000, 0xc0000000, 0xe0000000 or something such on 32 bit architectures), so there is a per-process limit that may be lower than the system limit (for example, a 32 bit process on Windows can only allocate 2 GB, even if the system is 64 bit). File mappings (such as the program itself and DLLs) further reduce the available space.

Answer (score 0):

A very general and theoretical answer would be no, it can not. One of the reasons it could possibly under very peculiar circumstances fail is that there would be some weird fragmentation of your available / allocatable memory. I wonder whether you're trying get (probably very minor) performance boost (skipping if pointer == NULL - kind of thing) or you're just wondering and want to discuss it, in which case you should probably use chat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, memory allocation often fails when you run out of memory space in a 32-bit application (can be 2, 3 or 4 GB depending on OS version and settings).  This would be due to a memory leak.  It can also fail if your OS runs out of space in your swap file.